# Maven Google App Engine plugin + Spring

Tags: eclipse, spring, google-app-engine, maven, spring-mvc

I want to use the the Maven Google App Engine plugin (https://github.com/maven-gae-plugin/maven-gae-plugin) to start a Google App Engine project with Spring MVC support. I'm interested in the Spring archetype they have. I tried to generate a project using `mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=net.kindleit -DarchetypeArtifactId=gae-archetype-spring \ -DarchetypeVersion=0.9.4 -DgroupId=com.myapp.test -DartifactId=testapp` but it didn't work. Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 3):

We're starting to push an official plugin, check out http://code.google.com/p/appengine-maven-plugin/ new archetypes are in the works.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem, I downloaded the source code and I added this line `<module>gae-archetype-spring</module>` to the root pom.xml in the modules tag. Then I installed the plugin in my local repo.

The developer missed adding this line I think after he added the spring-gae archetype.

ps: another issue the `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` need to be removed from the pom.xml inside the directory `gae-archetype-spring` for the pom.xml to be parseable.